# Permission denied error midway even after recursive chown

Tags: 14.04, permissions, python, chown

I have `chown`ed the directory like this:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/xyz
```

And then I ran a script which puts files to a directory gives me a permission denied error after some files are put.

The error is as follows:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/xyz/some/random/dir/data/outputs/xy.json
```

It is to be noted that this is like the 13th json file in the list. So, the previous 12 files have already been written successfully to the directory.

Tested this flow multiple times, and the same error occurs **midway** the process, which I found weird, as some files are being written before it suddenly throws this error.

**Where did I go wrong in the file permissions?**

---

It is a Python script, which does:

```
with open(os.path.join(output_dir,'{0}.json'.format(filename)),'w') as fout:
```

The error was from the Python script.

Permissions of the directory `/home/ubuntu/xyz`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Aug  4 05:13
```

Permissions of the directory `/home/ubuntu/xyz/some/random/dir/data/outputs/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Aug  4 05:13
```

Comment: if you want to know what is wrong with the file permissions, showing us the permissions of the file might be a good idea... Some information about the environment is also needed. I don't know what program throws an error `IOError: [Errno 13]` - I've never seen that before. So in what system and context and by what method are you copying the files?

Comment: @Zanna Thanks for helping. Updated the post. Let me know if the edit clears things up :)